# How do I switch to another scene in the Corona SDK?

Tags: android, lua, sdk, coronasdk

I have a main scene in the Corona SDK (main.lua) On this scene there is a button, when you click on which there should be a transition to another scene (home.lua). How do I do this? Preferably using composer

Comment: The main.lua should not be scene itself.

Answer (score 0):

Modified version of example from [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/touch/index.html)

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()
...


local object = display.newImage( "ball.png" )

local function onObjectTouch( event )
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then

    elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
        composer.gotoScene( "home" )   
    end
    return true
end
object:addEventListener( "touch", onObjectTouch )
```